# ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a **Linux VM (with CentOS 64 bit)** where I installed **Oracle Database 11g Express Edition**. The database is running, I can use sqlplus and I can create tables and stuff. However, when I run a certain SQL script which inserts a huge amount of random data (~2 million rows) I get this error:

```
ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation
```

I already tried to increase `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` with the command below. As far as I read this should solve the problem (but it doesn't) since it increases the memory.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = 40M scope = both;
```

However, the problem is that I can not set `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` higher than ~40M (which seems to be not sufficient). If I try to set it up to 100M or more I get another error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because specified value is invalid
ORA-47500: XE edition memory parameter invalid or not specified
```

**Any idea how I can solve this problem?** It is perfectly fine for me to re-install the whole database or whatever.

*PS.: I asked the same question on https://stackoverflow.com/ since I wasn't sure whether it is programming or database administration.*

Comment: Could you try to set SGA_TARGET to 0 and set MEMORY_TARGET to your desired value? Maybe AMM will let you allocate more PGA even on XE.

Comment: I can set `ALTER SYSTEM SET  SGA_TARGET  = 0;` and set `ALTER SYSTEM SET MEMORY_TARGET = 600M;`. After that I can set `ALTER SYSTEM SET PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = 200M scope = both;`. The 200M is much more than the 40M before but I still get the same `ORA-30009: Not enough memory` exception. Why I can't increase this values much more?

Comment: You understand that the PGA can't be bigger than the total amount of memory available to the database, right?

Comment: Please show us the query and the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips that might help you inserting huge amounts of data:

- use APPEND hint, this should solve your problem, as the data will go directly into the datafiles per-say.
- try to break the data into smaller chunk, and insert them sequentally
- use NOLOGGING mode to avoid frequent log-switchees (don't forget to enable it back afterwards!) - or at least increase the size of redo-log files
- avoid using cursors
- drop any indexes that you might have
- try to COMMIT less frequently (use a transaction for each chunk of data, and commit at the end)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ddaniel, but I can not change the SQL script itself. I can only setup the database in a different way. I'm sorry...

Comment: Thomas, still, some of these could be accomplished without altering the script; for instance the indexes could be dropped prior to the insert operation, you could begin a transaction, execute script, then commit it, and also the NOLOGGING mode does not depend on script.

Comment: None of those tips will reduce the memory required by a `connect by` query.